# Work with Spring Scheduler (Vaadin Chat and Spring Boot)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I created Vaadin Chat with Spring Boot. I wrote a sсheduler, I can’t add a function to it.  I need to take all the messages from the MySQL database, whose ID is more than the ID whick we took from the last message.

My Scheduler

```
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {

        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<LinkedHashMap> lasts = restService.getUnreadMessages(messageLast.getId());

        for (LinkedHashMap message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.get("fromV") + ": " + message.get("messageV")));
        }



    }
```

This sheduler is in class - Mainview

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private final MessagesInfoManager messagesInfoManager;
    private final RestService restService;
    private String username;
    private TextField textField;
    private Message messageLast;


    @Autowired
    public MainView(RestService restService) {
        this.messagesInfoManager = MessageConfigurator.getInstance().getChatMessagesInfoManager();
        addClassName("main-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);

        H1 header = new H1("Vaadin Chat");
        header.getElement().getThemeList().add("dark");

        add(header);

        askUsername();
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    private void askUsername() {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        TextField usernameField = new TextField();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start chat");

        layout.add(usernameField, startButton);

        startButton.addClickListener(click -> {
            username = usernameField.getValue();
            remove(layout);
            showChat(username);
        });

        add(layout);
    }

    private void showChat(String username) {
        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<Message> lasts = restService.getLast();
        for (Message message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.getFromV() + ": " + message.getMessageV()));
        }

        messageLast = lasts.get(lasts.size() - 1);

        add(messageList, createInputLayout(username, messageList));
        expand(messageList);
    }

    private Component createInputLayout(String username, MessageList messageList) {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.setWidth("100%");

        TextField messageField = new TextField();
        messageField.addKeyDownListener(Key.ENTER, keyDownEvent -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        sendButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        layout.add(messageField, sendButton);
        layout.expand(messageField);

        messageField.addFocusListener(event -> {
            for (Message message : messagesInfoManager.getMessagesByUI(getUI())) {
                if (!message.getFromV().equals(username)) {
                    message.setUnread(false);
                    this.restService.updateMessage(message.getId(), message);
                }
            }
        });

        sendButton.addClickListener(click -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        messageField.focus();

        return layout;
    }

    private void sender(TextField textField, MessageList messageList) {
        Message message = new Message(username, textField.getValue());
        restService.saveMessage(message);
        messageLast = message;
        this.textField = textField;
        messagesInfoManager.updateMessageUIInfo(new MessageInfo(messageList, message, this));
        textField.clear();
        textField.focus();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {

        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<LinkedHashMap> lasts = restService.getUnreadMessages(messageLast.getId());

        for (LinkedHashMap message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.get("fromV") + ": " + message.get("messageV")));
        }



    }
```

Repository

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM chatMessages WHERE id > :id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> getUnreadById(@Param("id") long id);
```

Comment: Can't add function to it. - What does this mean? Is the scheduler not executing? Did you try with @EnableScheduling?

Comment: Also, try adding "@Component" to the class with "@Scheduled" methods, for Spring to scan it.

Comment: Please take some time to investigate and describe the symptoms before posting a question - it will make it easier for anyone to provide a good anser.

Is the problem that the `scheduleFixedDelayTask` isn't run, or that it is run but the effects of it are not show? You can put a logging statement or something like `System.out.println("In scheduleFixedDelayTask")` in the method to find that out.

Comment: Why does `restService.getUnreadMessages(...)` return a `List<LinkedHashMap>` and not `List<Message>`?

Answer (score 1):

I can spot at least two problems in your example, but I cannot be sure those are the only ones

The first problem is that you're adding the messages to a newly created `MessageList` instance, but this instance isn't used anywhere. It's like writing notes on a piece of paper and then just immediately throwing the paper into the trashcan. You instead need to store a reference to the `MessageList` instance that you have added as a child component and add the new messages to that one.

The next problem is that `@Scheduled` will be run in a background thread whereas updates to Vaadin components will only be automatically reflected in the browser if they are done while processing a request from the user's browser, such as when the user clicks a button. To fix this, you need to enable `@Push` and you need to use the `access` method when updating the components so that Vaadin can prevent multiple threads from stepping on each others' toes and know when there are changes that need to be pushed out. See https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html for more information on this topic.

Comment: The `messageLast` field is also never updated inside the scheduled task, resulting each consecutive scheduled task fetch the same messages over and over.